Taking photographs outside court
I was talking with a friend of mine who recently raised an interesting point about the Criminal Justice Act 1925, section 41.
According to this section, it is an offence to take a photograph (including a portrait or sketch) of any judge, juror, witness, or party, when inside the courtroom, inside the court building, around its precincts, or when entering or leaving the aforesaid.
Yet we commonly see films and photographs of criminals around courthouses, often clearly depicting the court building in the frame, or at least strongly implying that the person is on their way to or from a court in the vicinity. I've seen press-published images of those on the very steps of the courthouse.
And of course, sketches are very commonly made of internal scenes from the courtroom depicting various people whilst the court is in session.
Is there case law further defining the applicability of CJA 1925 in this respect, or some other way to reconcile that law with normal practices?

Seems to be limited to judges, juries and witnesses.  (not plaintiffs, defendants or lawyers.)

@browsermator No, it clearly says "a party to any proceedings before the court, whether civil or criminal," which is plaintiffs and defendants.

Most depictions are US, or you mean in the UK?

@Trish, it definitely occurs in the UK.

Interesting question given the circumstances. In terms of sketching, artists make written notes and after emerging from court they then draw based on their memory and their notes. They don't draw in court.

I think you've misread it. The law prohibits photography and sketching within the court's buildings/land/property, not outside the court's property. Maybe you think "precinct" means "any place nearby" but it doesn't: it means an area with a specific boundary.

@StuartF, it prohibits whilst entering or leaving the building and/or precincts. Would a person on the steps of courthouse - i give that example - not be considered "within the precincts", or "entering/leaving the building"? Btw I'm looking for more than just a reading lesson - if the judge was on the train or at the front door of his own dwelling, I can accept he is not entering or leaving court, but many court buildings have large precinct areas, and I'm less satisfied that photographing a judge's car driving away from the court car park is not whilst he is "leaving the precincts".

The 1925 act is frequently quoted, so perhaps the UK restriction only dates from 1925, which is around the same time legislated restrictions came into force in the USA.  In any case, since that date, English Sketch Artists work from memory.
They don't 'take a sketch" when inside the courtroom, inside the court building, around its precincts, or when entering or leaving the aforesaid. They take a look at the participants, then go somewhere else and create.
In the USA, the rules are different. I don't think there were any legislated rules until the 1930's, when cameras became so disruptive they were banned. The existence of American court sketches going back to the first American courts, and the coincidence of dates, suggests that Sketch Artists were permitted in English courts prior to the 1925 legislation.

What about with regards to photographs taken on the steps of the courthouse?

I don't get to see UK television. Can you link to a photograph?

Consider this of Tommy Robinson leaving court for example: https://tinyurl.com/3mhc4kpr. You can see particularly that he's within a gated area there. I didn't choose him specifically btw - I just did a search for people leaving court! I've seen countless similar photos and films over time.

@Steve, I agree. The UK court system encourages open reporting, and the purpose of the law is only to enable proper operation of the courts, but they are aware that photographers outside the court create problems for people entering or leaving, and that photograph shows they are taking a very narrow of enforcing.

I'm not sure they really do encourage open reporting in the manner you suggest. When was the home address of the judge last reported, or jurors barraged with photographs? I'd suggest what we see could be consistent with both the existence of a lawless paparazzi, and lax or corrupt police enforcement (given the known links of police officers to the privately-owned lying press). So I'm still unclear on what the law is regarded to be.
